# How do I clarify or appeal moderator's action

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation

Several times I saw moderator actions that are at least unclear or seem inappropriate. E.g.

- One of my questions was incorrectly transferred from a Stack Exchange site to other one without any apparent way to object that.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60527021/the-combobox-and-jtextfields-are-not-highlighted-in-green-says-cannot-find-symb) by a first time user was closed as off-topic - which is not true. It is not properly phrased and lacks necessary details, but is about specific programming problem. I think that first time users especially need more guidance in how to use the site than just telling that question is off-topic.

Should an etiquette include some voting or a way to object moderator's actions? Is there a way to demand explanation of the decision? What is the procedure for reverting moderator's actions?
If not what is the rationale of not allowing appeals/clarification/reversion of moderator actions?

Comment: It was closed as off topic *because* it lacks those details, you simply don't have the reputation to see the full close reason. The full close reason - *"Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question. Closed 11 days ago by #########.* ***(Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege)***" - Take specific note of the last part

Comment: I would suggest that demanding anything is unlikely to produce a good response, here or anywhere else in life... The procedure for revering a moderator's actions is to bring the moderator's actions up on Meta, to flag for moderator attention (where there are multiple moderators on the site, moderators will not handle complaints about their own actions), or to use the Contact Us link at the bottom of every page. These actions are explained in [the help center page about site moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60527021/2029983) was closed because it didn't "include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem." which is 100% true. All the OP did was post some code. Some random code with no context does not make a question.

Comment: You need [3,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60527021/2029983) to see the reason a question is closed; you currently only have 1,700. As a result you cannot see the reason, and thus will be presented with the generic reason. As for your migrated question, without a link, we would have to guess why it was, but I suspect the reason was correct too.

Comment: On SO moderator actions are always visible as one way street. Without no clear way to object. So let me keep my "demand" in there. So many comments but no one bothered to add answer? Meta is not a Q/A?

Comment: I suspected that meta might be a hostile place, but now I see that behavior on main site is not an accident.

Comment: @HereticMonkey actually this is the first place where I see such reaction to a straightforward question. Maybe in my 45 years I was just lucky to stay away from places like this one. Thanks for life advice, though complete unexpected here.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey If one breaks my stuff, then I have my right to demand an explanation from them.

Comment: I was not telling you not to demand. I was simply suggesting that doing so was less likely to provide the desired response. Your experience may vary. And of course, that was one sentence of several in the comment, the remainder being an explanation of your options for objecting to a moderator's actions, which is what you asked for. Perhaps some introspection on your part is warranted?

Answer (score 21):

Let's flip this on its head, then.

Can you, given all of the code in that question, reproduce the issue that the OP is facing on your machine?

If you *can*, then that's awesome and that also implies that anyone *else* could do that.

If you *can't*, then the question should *remain* closed until such a time that it can be run locally.

No one here is a mind reader, and we don't have the insights into the OP's exact environment.  Providing as much detail as reasonably possible to get us to that state is, bluntly, the ***only*** thing we ask.  Not meeting us even that far makes it tough to justify reopening the question.

Comment: I wonder why it is upvoted. It does not answer my question.