# I do not like the rules of moderation for newcomers. How do I opt out from review queues?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, first-post-review

The review queues are always full and the queue icon on the top right is permanently marked as having new items in them. To clean it up I would probably need tens of minutes of my quality time.

Since I am a bit tired defending newcomers from overly strict moderation, I do not want to be bothered with reviews any more. How do I opt out of that?

Comment: The moderation "rules" are for everyone, not just newcomers. What you call "overly strict" is, to many of us, overly liberal.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *opt out*? What's the issue with just not visiting the review queues? I fail to see why this needs to be a feature. On the other hand, a feature request for [turning off Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407035) seems to be popular, and well received, so maybe you're on to something.

Comment: *"a bit tired defending new comers from overly strict moderation"* - I'm tired of newcomers being treated as though they're special users which shouldn't be subject to the same rules as everyone else, but hey, we can't all get what we want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hide review notifications?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343816/how-can-i-hide-review-notifications)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - the last time you made a review on SO proper (or, judging by your network profile, on any site) was in March 2020, are you still tired of that? And by "defending newcomers" do you refer to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394658/11407695) Meta post of yours? Were you suspended for the last year or just decided to rant about review queues (btw, there are multiple of them - which one do you talk about?)

Answer (score 29):

You opt out of the review queue by deciding not to participate in it.

Moderation is a volunteer activity; nobody is *required* to do it.

Comment: This isn't fair as t is the only badges that are reachable for most

Comment: @nbk: I don't see what badges have to do with it. We shouldn't be changing moderation requirements just so that people can get badges.

Comment: @JonSkeet, some user can' reply as fast as knowledgable user as you are, so they can't get any upvotes, that is why they try with this to look better, so that people will trust them. As i mention on other answer, you and other high rep get credits low get nothing and can't get anything, only when they are really lucky and catch one where high reps haven'zt anwered

Comment: @nbk: Badges don't really have much to do with trust, insofar as moderation is concerned.  Rep is the actionable currency.

Comment: @nbk: There are plenty of tags outside the main popular language tags with so little competition that the median time for the first answer is measured in hours or days, like [Forth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forth) or [Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi). Such answers, especially comprehensive ones, get a surprising number of upvotes. You can even post actual answers [if others are not willing to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67378948/fractional-exponentiation-in-forth).

Comment: @PeterMortensen you habe 28k and i 20k which i thing are hard earned, with lots of answers, which have no upvotes or are accepted, but the problem for newcomers, is that they can't get a food on the ground as high reps answer or close faster than lucky Kuke, thtat is why they try their luck with the reviews, but there they find diffrent moderator opinions, and bans which nobody can understand, as they are asked for their opionion on the matter and then get punished for it.

Answer (score -24):

It seems there is no opt-out. Here is the solution I have been using for a long while.
You can use ad blocker plugin in your browser to hide/block particular elements on the page.
For example, with [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin), right click (context menu) on the review queue icon, pick "Block element...", and create a rule to filter out elements you do not want.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do reviewing, but don't want to help with the First Posts queue. That's OK, but can you just ignore it?